# display:inline isn't making elements appear on one row

Tags: html, css, forms, inline

I have a table with a class of "standard-table."  When I put input boxes, selects, or textareas in combination with another element into a cell, they appear on two separate lines even though there aren't any 
s present.

Here's the CSS for the class:

```
/* Table
====================================*/
table.standard-table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border:none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    box-shadow:  0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
}

table.standard-table th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #404040;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.standard-table td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.standard-table th:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.standard-table td {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: #e0e0e0 1px solid;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
}

table.standard-table tr:hover td {background-color: #fafafa;}

table tr.altrow { background-color: #cccccc; }

table th {text-align: left; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top; }
```

Here's an example of a row that's having the issue:

```
<tr>
    <th valign='top'>Items in Package</th>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='categories[]' value='test' /> Test 
        <input type='text' name='budget_1' placeholder='Budget' style='width:200px;' onkeyup=\"if (/[a-z\s,$]/ig.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[a-z\s,$]/ig,'')\" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried adding "display:inline", "display:inline-cell", "display:inline-table", and all the others, but nothing is placing the checkbox, text, and then input box on the same line.

Comment: Is your table's width is enough, for placing these element in same line?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
float: left;
```

This will force elements to inline. In addition to this, use;

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Comment: I added "style='float:left'" to the <td> tag and it just shortened the width of the cell.

Comment: OK. You may set up a demo at jsfiddle.net , save it and post link here. Let me know your expected out. I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align`

http://jsfiddle.net/2RL8t/3/

Its technically already aligned in the middle vertically, but I don't think visually doesn't look like it is.

Comment: I feel as if you have some code that is modifying the the checkbox.  Please create a fiddle or show us a screen shot of what your issue is.